# Black Screen in blue Stacks when running AndEngine program

Tags: andengine, bluestacks

Below are the complete codes of the program. When i run the program in BlueStacks  a black screen was appeared. My Video card driver is working fine and updated. Please help me to find the problem.

```
public class StartActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private Camera mCamera;
private Texture mTexture;
private TextureRegion mSplashTextureRegion;

    @Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    this.mTexture = new Texture(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mSplashTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/Splashscreen.png", 0, 0);

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);

    /* Center the splash on the camera. */
    final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

    /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
    final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);

    return scene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
}
}
```

Comment: i hope someone could help me about this problem

Comment: There is any Error in the Logcat?

Comment: THere is no  error in Logcat. i cant figure out why this problem occur

Answer (score 0):

What's the resolution of the picture? if is higher than 512*512 then you need to change this line:

```
this.mTexture = new Texture(1024, 10244, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```